# Is there an atom of non-trivial measure on countable compact metric space?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be compact metric space and it has no non-atomic Borel Probability measures. Then by Theorem 8.1. p.53 in "Probability meausres on metric spaces , K.R. Parthasarathy"$X$ is countable.

What can about converse of this theorem?

Precisely suppose that  $X$ is an countable and $\mu$ is a non-trivial measure, for example $X= \{a, b\}\cup\{a_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}$ where $lim_{i\to \infty}a_i=a$ and $im_{i\to -\infty}a_i=b$.

Is there an atom of $\mu$ in $X$?

Comment: If you want countably additive measures then, trivially, yes. If all elements have measure zero then so does the whole space. If you are fine with finitely additive measures then no, see [Natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density).

Comment: @Conifold, Thanks. In my research, I know that $\mu$ is a Borel Probability measure. Can I say that it is countably additive measure?

Comment: [Borel measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_measure) are defined on a σ-algebra, so countably additive.